# TextBox positioning in OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am new in OpenXML. I am trying to create the word(.docx) file having simple text and images in it using openxml. I have already mentioned all this in my earlier post:

[My Earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425646/how-to-add-text-on-desired-coordinates-on-new-word-file-using-openxml/39627009?noredirect=1#comment66688109_39627009)

I am using this code

```
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create("E:\\test11.docx", DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            mainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            ParagraphProperties oParagraphProperties = para.AppendChild(new ParagraphProperties());
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            Text tt = new Text(str);
            run.AppendChild(tt);
            RunProperties runProp = new RunProperties(); // Create run properties.
            RunFonts runFont = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Cambria(Headings)", HighAnsi = "Cambria(Headings)" };
            Bold bold = new Bold();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color Color1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color() { Val = "0EBFE9" };
            Italic ita = new Italic();
            runProp.Append(bold);
            runProp.Append(Color1);
            runProp.Append(ita);
            FontSize size = new FontSize();
            size.Val = new StringValue((fontSize * 2).ToString());  // 48 half-point font size
            runProp.Append(runFont);
            runProp.Append(size);
            run.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);
        }
```

That works fine for creating simple .docx file but i am having some coordinates and width height issues in text boxes. You can have a look on attached screenshots for understanding properly the issue.

[image: My Output]
My output file

[image: Original file]

Original File

I want to create a file having text on same position like **Original file**. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Issues like writing the correct C# code that will produce a certain Open XML document can be solved easily using a sample document and the *Document Reflector* that comes with the Open XML SDK:

1. Download and install the latest version of the Open XML SDK ([OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425))
2. Open the **Open XML SDK Productivity Tool** (`OpenXmlSdkTool.exe`) located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\tool` (when installed to the default location).
3. Create a sample document with the desired formatting and open it in the tool.
4. Click on ***Reflect Code***
5. Copy the generated code to your project and adjust where needed, e.g. by replacing the static text with your content.

Comment: Thanks Dirk for your suggestion. I have already tried it but not able to understand the flow and functionality of the code. Any other idea for positioning of text boxes.

Comment: @Ashish: Can you provide more information on where you are stuck?

Comment: As i have shown you in my screenshots. I have all the text and formatting information. The problem is: I am not able to write the text on desired location(coordinates) of the page.

Comment: So why not use the code generated by the document reflector, and just replace the text values from your sample document with the desired content?

Comment: you can have a look on my previous query for better understanding my problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425646/how-to-add-text-on-desired-coordinates-on-new-word-file-using-openxml/39627009?noredirect=1#comment66688109_39627009)