# How to insert new SmartArt in PowerPoint using OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, openxml

I want to create new SmartArt Hierarchy diagram in Powerpoint using Open XML coding C#. I tried searching anywhere but can not find solution to working. Anyone can help me for this.

I found the link as below, but it only works when available 1 smart art template

http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/17/p/5186/158159.aspx#158159

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating SmartArt objects by hand in code is a rather complex task. You need to add a diagram to a slide, which consist of both a layout part and a data model. The code for this soon can get pretty complex.

It is therefore a lot easier to rely on a tool that takes care of the code generation. Luckily, such a tool exists: the **Open XML SDK Productivity Tool**.

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40127452/40347) for instructions how to use this tool. This answer refers to Word documents but can be applied to PowerPoint presentations as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!