# Python- How to add text on desired coordinates on new word file

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

If the size of the document (.doc) say 1000x3000 (WidthxHeight), I need to place a text "Hello" at 400X300 coordinate points.

How to do it using python + any libraries? (Ubuntu platform)

Similar kind of problem has been addressed using Java
[How to add text on desired coordinates on new word file using openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425646/how-to-add-text-on-desired-coordinates-on-new-word-file-using-openxml)

Answer (score 3):

You can't place regular text at an arbitrary position. But you can use a textbox instead. Make sure to set top and left margins to 0. The **top** left corner of the text will then be at the specified coordinates.

Unfortunately, [Python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doesn't support [floating shapes](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html). But you can do it using COM Automation on a Windows computer where Word is installed. You need [PyWin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) which can also be downloaded from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32).

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Add()

tb = doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 400, 300, 100, 100)
tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello"
tb.TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
tb.TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
tb.Fill.Visible = 0
tb.Line.Visible = 0

doc.SaveAs2("Hello.docx")
doc.Close()
word.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. Kindly share your thoughts

Comment: You didn't state this in your question, instead you said **any** library.  

I'm afraid there will be no solution available. The [python-docx issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/159) is open since 2015.

Comment: For anyone wanting to downvote this answer because its for Windows and not for Linux: the OP added *Ubuntu platform* only after my answer, it wasn't mentioned in the original post and once we're talking about Microsoft Word (see also tag ms-word) it would be safe to assume that we're on Windows.

Comment: #Stef, Have I ever mentioned Windows in the question initially or later?. Why anyone should assume that Windows is safe. You dumbo!!