# How I can create TextBox in python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I need to write some text in TextBox element, to it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg39W.png)

How I can make it by python-docx? Or I need to make it by oxml?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`python-docx` currently has no API support for "floating" text aka. Text boxes.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I can create this element by oxml?
I see it have a structure like this https://prnt.sc/135kpwb

Comment: You can use [win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201077/python-how-to-add-text-on-desired-coordinates-on-new-word-file/57202827#57202827)